# TemplateDoesNotExist django rest framewok

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I try to return HTML responses, but i have a TemplateDoesNotExist problem.
[image]

**ModelViewSet**

```
class ProfileList(APIView):
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    template_name = 'test.html'
    def get(self, request):
        queryset = Profile.objects.all()
        return Response({'profiles': queryset})
```

**Strucute of app**

[image]

Comment: The temlatetemplate should be put under templates, so `profile/templates/test.html`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following,

In your profile app create templates/profile/test.html .

make sure 'rest_framework' in settings.py app list

Mr.Willem Van Onsem suggested same